# What does "power coming up" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

This scene comes from the scene in the movie "The Aviator" in which Howard Hughes is making a first test flight of a mammoth plane Hercules(or The Spruce Goose) which was one of his biggest projects.
The line is uttered when Howard pushes on the thrust lever of the Hercules.

"Power coming up" and this line is received by the member of the crew by repeating "Power coming up"

**Does this simply mean " to increase"?**

8. To increase in value.

*Luckily, housing prices in our neighborhood have come up since we bought our house*. (Farlex Dictionary Of Idioms)

To become higher in value: *Their grades came up once they started studying more* (American Heritage Dictionary).

Comment: I know nothing about flying aircraft, but presumably he is warning the crew that he is accelerating the engine and they should prepare for an increase in speed - so, a combination of 'increasing' and 'about to happen'.

Answer (score 1):

It does mean *increasing*, but in that context I would understand it as *increasing from zero towards the desired value* - hence the use of "coming", meaning "moving towards where we want to be".